# Does the installation of Jekyll need GCC on OSX?

Tags: macos, jekyll

[Jekyll Installation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/) says:

> GCC and Make (in case your system doesn’t have them installed, which you can check by running gcc -v and make -v in your system’s command line interface)

I am using macOS Sierra. And I have installed Command Line Tools (CLT) for Xcode. And `gcc -v` produces:

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

It means that I have clang installed. Do I still need to install GCC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually you set this:

```
CC=clang
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like I was wrong ;)

You don't have to install GCC.

It should be enough to:

**1. Install Ruby**

I prefer to install from sources: https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.4/ruby-2.4.1.tar.gz

```
> ./configure --prefix=$HOME/opt/ruby
> make
> make install
```

**2. Install RubyGems**

Again, I prefer to install from sources: https://rubygems.org/pages/download

```
> export PATH=$HOME/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
> ruby setup.rb
```

**3. Change repo location**

I don't compile Ruby with ssh. In that case, I have to change the ruby gems repo

```
> gem sources -r https://rubygems.org/
> gem sources -a http://rubygems.org/
```

(*if you want to build with OpenSSL, take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/?p=3262 There is a sample related to building OpenSSL at macOS*)

**4. You can install Jekyll**

```
> gem install jekyll
> jekyll --version
jekyll 3.5.2
```

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of people (who are not using Linux) are having trouble with setting up Jekyll. If you want no problems, you can also use [Cloud9](http://c9.io/) for Jekyll. Cloud9 is an online virtual Linux environment (and IDE).

The steps are:

1. create a free account on Cloud9
2. create an empty project (Ubuntu)
3. type on the Cloud9 terminal: gem install jekyll
4. create an empty _config.yml file in the project root
5. create a index.md file in the project root
6. type on the Cloud9 terminal: jekyll serve –host $IP –port $PORT –baseurl ''
7. your (very basic) website is now running ‘locally’ on Cloud9 and can be accessed by clicking 'Preview Running Application'

I created an archive with some Jekyll scripts to get going. You can find it on [jekyllcodex.org](http://jekyllcodex.org).