# Installation error when installing Ruby for Jekyll

Tags: ruby, python-3.x, jekyll

I'm running on Windows 10 Enterprise, build 1703. I have Anaconda 4.4.0 and Python 3.6 installed. I'm running bash and Ubuntu Linux was installed o.k.

I'm trying to install Ruby for Jekyll (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/#installing-jekyll).

The install command is:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev build-essential
```

and it gives the error:

```
root@bigsur:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# sudo apt-get install ruby2.3 ruby2.3-dev build-essential
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
root@bigsur:/mnt/c/Windows/System32#
root@bigsur:/mnt/c/Windows/System32#
root@bigsur:/mnt/c/Windows/System32# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3.5:
 python3.5 depends on python3.5-minimal (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3); however:
  Version of python3.5-minimal on system is 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.1.
 python3.5 depends on libpython3.5-stdlib (= 3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.3); however:
  Package libpython3.5-stdlib:amd64 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python3.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libapt-inst2.0:amd64 (1.2.24) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unable to truncate for updated status of 'libapt-inst2.0:amd64': Invalid argument
root@bigsur:/mnt/c/Windows/System32#
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Charles

Comment: You might want to consider using Cloud9: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144384/2397550

Answer (score 0):

I read many posts on the Internet that said the best way to install Jekyll was to install by way of a linux subsystem.  I now realize that this is bad advice.  After running into trouble (see above), I started over.  I found that Build 1703 of Windows 10 Enterprise already had the infrastructure to install Jekyll with the instructions at: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/.  I followed these instructions and I now have a clean installation of Jekyll.  Don't bother installing Ubuntu. You don't need it, and you will save over 700 MBytes of disc space.

Charles