# Jekyll on Mac no Admin access (No homebrew, Ruby, Rvm, cURL)

Tags: javascript, ruby, xcode, jekyll

I am trying to install Jekyll on my school computer, therefore i have no Root/Admin access. I don't have Ruby, RVM, cURL, sudo, homebrew and make. Though I do have Git. Every time I try one of the commands it comes back with

```
bash: ruby: command not found
```

(whatever program it is).

I am using MacOs Sierra and have XCode installed

Comment: what OS? I'm assuming it's a Mac running some form of macOS since you said homebrew

Comment: Is Xcode installed/can you install it?

Comment: I am using MacOs Sierra and I do have XCode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have unsufficient rights, and/or you are on a shared computer, I would choose to use Cloud9 to run admin on Linux. I gave this answer earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46144384/2397550